# Unable to locate web element using Selenium Webdriver in python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to provide a text input to the below Web element.

```
<input class="lui-search__input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" maxlength="5000" q-placeholder="Object.Listbox.Search" ng-model="query" ng-disabled="disabled" autocomplete spellcheck="false" ng-trim="false" type="text" qva-blur="blurred()" qva-focus="autoFocus" qv-escape="escape($event)" qv-enter="enter($event)" aria-label="Search in listbox" placeholder="Search in listbox">.
```

I am using the below code. But I am getting an error saying, Unable to locate the element/Timeout.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Assuming driver is already initialized
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # Wait up to 10 seconds

# Wait for the element to be clickable and then send Enter
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='lui-search__input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched']")))
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Without resource it's difficult to identify the reason.

Comment: resource in the sense? The entire HTML page?

Comment: Yep, your site or full HTML structure path from body to your element